# Drew Wilson's autocomplete help!

Tags: jquery, autocomplete

I used [Drew Wilson's autocomplete](http://code.drewwilson.com/entry/autosuggest-jquery-plugin), its really well made but poorly documented. I am able to initialize the autocomplete plugin, but i cannot get the values selected.

I tried using this:

```
$("#txtReceipient").autoSuggest(data.items, {
                    minChars: 2,
                    matchCase: false,
                    selectedItemProp: "name",
                    searchObjProps: "name",
                    selectedValuesProp: "value",
                    startText: "Type the name of the receipient here"
                });
```

and tried to retrieve the values by:

```
alert($('#txtReceipient').val());
```

I'm getting undefined value as the alert returns. im at the end of my wits. help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved it.

a straightforward documentation would have helped a lot:

```
alert($(".as-values").val());
```

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, it is not documented well.
But if you look at the "**jquery.autoSuggest.js**" you can find the answer. There he's given some default options like this:

```
var defaults = { 
            asHtmlID: false,
            startText: "Enter Name Here",
            emptyText: "No Results Found",
            preFill: {},
            ... 
            ...
```

Here "**asHtmlID**" property is set to false by default. if you provide any name  while initiating autosuggest then you can easily get values from it.

for example,

```
$(function(){
  $("#txt").autoSuggest(data.items, {selectedItemProp: "name", searchObjProps: "name", startText: "", keyDelay: 50, minChars: 1,asHtmlID: "username" });
```

for the above example if you alert like,

```
alert($("#as-values-username").val());
```

you'll get the value. Hope it'll help some users in future..